# Add delete and arrow key into Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am performing date validation and now I am doing that user can only enter `numbers` ,`/`and `backspace` so now I want to add 2 more keys into my regular expression. I want to add `delete` and `arrow keys` so what will change I should do in my Regular Expression .This is my code

```
<input type="text" id="date" name="date" onkeypress="check(event,this);"  />
```

this is me Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function check(evt, id)
{

 var value = id.value;

 var theEvent = evt || window.event;
 var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
 key = String.fromCharCode( key );

 var regex = /[0-9|\b|/]/;

 if( !regex.test(key)) 
 {
  theEvent.returnValue = false;

  if(theEvent.preventDefault) 
   theEvent.preventDefault();
 }   
}



</script>
```

Thanks waiting for your help.

Comment: if you think you found the solution, check the notes I added in my answer they might help fixing your code to function as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can skip the input validation if arrow, delete and backspace keys were pressed

```
function check(evt, id)
{

 var value = id.value;

 var theEvent = evt || window.event;
 var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

 // Don't validate the input if below arrow, delete and backspace keys were pressed 
 if(key == 37 || key == 38 || key == 39 || key == 40 || key == 8 || key == 46) { // Left / Up / Right / Down Arrow, Backspace, Delete keys
     return;
 }

 key = String.fromCharCode( key );
 var regex = /[0-9|/]/;

 if( !regex.test(key)) 
 {
  theEvent.returnValue = false;

  if(theEvent.preventDefault) 
   theEvent.preventDefault();
 }   
}
```

Comment: This really is a poor way to mask input, since keypresses are not the only way that text can be entered into a field. Anyway, if this works for you, then you'll also need to add `home`, `end`, `pgup`, `pgdown` keys.

Comment: This code will not work with the signs of (, & and %,

Answer (score 1):

you should use on change and force change onkeyup to check the current value.

mistakes you have:

1- your regex should be the inverse, your current one checks if the value contains any of these but you want your value to not have other value.

2- you should escape the slash (/) character like this \/ so that it won't be assumed as the end of regex and the rest becomes modifiers!

Example:

```
document.getElementById('date').onchange = function(){
  var regex = /[^\d\/]/g;
  if(regex.test(this.value)) {console.log(false); return false;}
  else {console.log(true); return true;}
};

document.getElementById('date').onkeyup = function(){
  this.onchange();
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ehacam/1/edit)**

note: make sure you validate the whole date as dd/mm/yyyy or whatever your format is, right before sumission

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just check the actual value of the element, rather than the keypresses which create the value?

You can use the `oninput` event for that.

Comment: I want to restrict user to input to add some characters

Comment: oninput event is not supported in older browser (specially IE8) and its quite buggy in IE9. Combo of onchange, onpaste & onpropertychange could be a workaround although.

Comment: @AzamAlvi: that's exactly what `oninput` is for. Your current suggestion for checking keypresses doesn't cover the many ways that you can input (possibly invalid) data. For example, right-click + Paste, drag+drop text, and so on. @roasted If support for out-of-date browsers is required, then yes, you'll need to do some hacks, but it's not a good answer.