# Jquery - Regex keypress action different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, google-chrome, firefox

I am using this regex and this code for number only input

```
var numRegex = "[0-9\b]";
```

and

```
$('.numOnly').keypress(function(e){
    var regex = new RegExp(numRegex);
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }});
```

My code works in Chrome well include Numeric input, Backspace, Return Key, Home, End, Shift, and Ctrl but in firefox I only can do type Numeric and backspace.

Is there any better solution of using numeric typing and another needed stuff using Regex?

Thank you

Comment: Check this SO link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164239/add-delete-and-arrow-key-into-regular-expression for a solution

Comment: Can you define "another needed stuff"? What characters exactly should be allowable/disallowable? You may find explicitly disallowing characters with a negative match regular expression works more predictably. This one excludes all letters: var numRegex = "[^A-Za-z]";

Comment: Why use JQuery, use `<input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" name="numOnly" />`

Comment: another needed stuff means what that I type before like Backspace, Return Key, Home, End, Shift, and Ctrl Buttons

Comment: @user2340218 thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" name="numOnly" />
```

No need for special JQuery handling. The `(event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ?` check is meant to support BACKSPACE and DELETE keys in FireFox.